# Windows Forms application - Datagridview data issue

Tags: c#, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to download datagridview to an excel. Below is the code i am using.

//X - Values

```
     string[] arrRootCause = {"Batch Issue","Change Request","CICS Online Entry Error","Data Conversion Issue","Data Requirement Incorrect", "GS Code Issue","Incorrect in FS","In-house Code Issue","Integration Error","JCL/PARAM/PROC Issue","Load issue","Missing in FS","Others","Query","Region Data Incorrect","TBA","Understanding Issue","VisionPLUS Base code Issue"};
```

//Y1 and Y2 values:

```
      int[] TCStatus2 = { 3, 4, 53, 23, 53, 63, 83, 93, 13, 3, 93, 73, 43, 43, 23, 33, 43, 53 };
      int[] TCStatus3 = { 53, 42, 5, 23, 23, 93, 13, 33, 63, 36, 13, 11, 63, 13, 93, 73, 13, 73 };
```

//Taking data into List

```
      List<StackedBarChartData> sbcData = new List<StackedBarChartData>();

       for (int i = 0; i < arrRootCause.Length; i++)
       {
           StackedBarChartData sb = new StackedBarChartData();
           sb.Y1Values = TCStatus3[i];
           sb.Y2Values = TCStatus2[i];
           sb.XValues = arrRootCause[i];
           sbcData.Add(sb);
       }

       dataGridView1.DataSource = sbcData;
```

After i execute the windows form application I am getting output as below,

```
       XValues                Y1Values    Y2Values
       Batch Issue              53           3
       Change Request           42           4
       CICS Online Ent...        5          53
       Data Conversion...       23          23
       Data Requiremen…         23          53
       GS Code Issue            93          63
       Incorrect in FS          13          83
       In-house Code I...       33          93
       Integration Err...       63          13
       JCL/PARAM/PROC ...       36           3
       Load issue               13          93
       Missing in FS            11          73
       Others                   63          43
       Query                    13          43
       Region Data Inc...       93          23
       TBA                      73          33
       Understanding I...       13          43
```

As you can see above, CICS Online Ent... is coming instead of CICS Online Entry Error. Same is happening with some other strings in arrRootCause.

I tried increasing the width of the column, but of no use.

Can anyone help me in understanding what is the problem.

TIA.

Comment: Tell us, that what will happen when you increase the width of first column?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I increase the width of the column, it only column width is increasing but I am not getting the full string value into the column.

Comment: Use AutoSizeMode property of your column

Comment: Hi Shabbir. I tried using                                           DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView.Columns[0];
    column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;... But still  same issue

Comment: Do the getter of sb.XValues cut the string to length 18 by default?

Comment: Hi Eric, I am not doing any operation of cutting the string to length to 18. It is taking  by default I guess. I am not sure how to change the default value.

Comment: Can you write here StackedBarChartData class?

Comment: Here you go...                                                      public class StackedBarChartData
    {
        public string XValues { get; set; }
        public int Y1Values { get; set; }
        public int Y2Values { get; set; }
     }

Comment: Maybe you should convert your list to DataTable first and assign to Datasource later.

Comment: Hi, I tried as you suggested. But it is still the same issue. How can we remove the default character length to 18?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/thread/168444/how-to-set-datagridview-default-columns-width.aspx